# Javasctipt scientific notation override

Tags: javascript, overriding, scientific-notation

I am trying to write a code that will figure out the largest product of 5 consecutive numbers in a given number.
The code I have attempts to convert the number into an array and then for-loop through the array, multiplying every 5 consecutive single digit numbers and comparing it with the last.
Once the number I pass through the function exceeds 21 digits, I'm guessing the computer converts the number into scientific notation which throws the whole function off.
Here's the code, where it runs fine with 21 digits:

```
function func(value){
    var number = value;
    console.log(number);
    var output = [];
    sNumber = number.toString();
    console.log(sNumber);
    for (var i = 0; i < sNumber.length; i++) {
        output.push(+sNumber.charAt(i));
    }
    console.log(output);
    var productToCompare;
    var largerProduct = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < output.length - 4; j++) {
        productToCompare = output[j]*output[j+1]*output[j+2]*output[j+3]*output[j+4];
        console.log(productToCompare);
        if (productToCompare > largerProduct) {
            largerProduct = productToCompare;
        }
    }
    return largerProduct;
}

func(13245678901234567890);
```

Soon as I add another digit:

```
func(123465789012345678901);
```

It starts using scientific notation.
Is this due to the nature of Javascript, the computer I'm using, the compiler or what?

Comment: why not keeping the input number as a string?

Comment: @6502 I'm trying to input a large number and then treating each digit as a single independent number. So 12345 will be treated as 5 separate numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with a lot of things you'll run up against limitations of the fundamental data types used in JavaScript. In this case it seems to be a limit of the integer type.

The number 13245678901234567890 fits inside a 64-bit integer. Adding another digit pushes it into a range that cannot be represented that way so a floating-point number is required.

When testing this in different JavaScript engines you might get different values. Anything beyond 2147483648 is liable to end up cast as a floating point value.

Whenever you're doing mathematical calculations, try to avoid doing string computations on them. The string representation of a number is rather arbitrary and is not to be trusted.

What you should be doing is dividing by some factor of 10 and doing modulo-10 to get the individual digits.

Comment: In 64-bit Safari this seems to be the case. 13245678901234567890 ends up showing as 13245678901234567000.

Comment: Dividing and using modulo sounds like the way I should go, but is there a way to override scientific notation confidently? I realize I can use .toPrecsion, but since I'm working on a number I can't use: `value.toPrecision(value.length)`. I can simply count the number of digits but it can become annoying with large numbers. I also tried .toPrecision(25) or example and after 16 digits it appears that the computer is making up numbers by itself...

Comment: If you're determined to smash around really big numbers, you could try using [a bignum library for JavaScript](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum). Keep in mind these are usually considerably slower than native types, but in your case the performance might be acceptable.

Comment: Don't forget to read up on [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) if you're a bit hazy. You will run into trouble if you don't [understand their limitations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Remember that floating point values are always considered approximations, so part of it will be "made up".

Comment: @tadman concerning my question on counting the digits in the number, I realized I can simply assign a variable to convert the number to a string and use .length off of that variable. Thanks for all the links, I'll definitely look into them.

Comment: @tadman: that's why I said unit-accurate. If you try to add 1 to 2**53 you will see that the number doesn't change.

Comment: I was just confirming it's at the 53-bit mark and not 64-bit as I'd supposed.